# Change add button django admin if data filtrin

Tags: django

I new her and need help
I create a few models:
Customer
Orders

How to make the ADD button dynamic
If I use a filter and my url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/catalog/order/?order_customer__id=3, in this case pass the following value to the button <a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'add ' %}?order_customer={{cl.result_list.0.order_customer.id}}"
To prompt you to fill out the form when creating a new record. Accordingly, the url should look like this
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/catalog/order/add/?order_customer=3

If the filter is missing url http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/catalog/order/, the button has a default value
Accordingly, when switching to the creation form, the url has a standard value
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/catalog/order/add

Django 3.2.6
addons smart_selects

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """docstring for Customer."""
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Назва юридичної особи/ФОП', help_text='Введіть поністю назву юридичної особи чи фізичної особи підприємця')
    customer_inn = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='ЄДРПОУ', help_text='Введеіть ЄДРПОУ для юридичної особи чи ідентифікаційний код для ФОП')
    customer_adress = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Юридична адреса клієнта' , help_text='Притриймуйтесь формату аналогічно витягу ЄДР. Наприклад: 79000, Область, Район, Місто/Селище, вулиця/проспект Назва вулиці, Номебр будинку, квартира')
    customer_ceo = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Керівник/підписант')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Клієнт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Клієнти'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return self.customer_name

class Order(models.Model):
    order_customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Клієнт")
    order_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заявки')
    order_adress = ChainedForeignKey(
        'MarketAdress',
        chained_field = "order_customer",
        chained_model_field= "customermarkeradress",
        show_all = False,
        auto_choose = True,
        sort = True,
        verbose_name= 'Адреса точки')
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Номер заявки')
#    oder_brand = models.ForeignKey('CustomerBrand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Назва вивіски")
    oder_brand = ChainedForeignKey(
        'CustomerBrand',
        chained_field = "order_customer",
        chained_model_field= "customer",
        show_all = False,
        auto_choose = True,
        sort = True,
        verbose_name= 'Вивіска')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заявка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заявки'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return str(self.oder_brand)
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):


    list_display = ['customer_name', 'customer_inn', 'сontract', 'orders_lists', 'orders_add']
    inlines = [OrderInline, EnvironmentActInstanceInline]

    def сontract(self, obj):
        link_buttom = reverse('downloadWordcontarct', args=[obj.pk])
        return mark_safe(f'<a class="button" label="Догорів" href="{link_buttom}">Сформувати</a>')
    сontract.short_description = "Договір"

    def orders_lists(self, obj):
        argsus=obj.pk
        link_buttom = reverse("admin:catalog_order_changelist") + "?" + "order_customer__id=" + str(argsus)
        #return format_html('<a href="">{} order</a>', link_buttom)
        return mark_safe(f'<a class="button" label="Заявки" href="{link_buttom}">Перейти до заявки</a>')
    orders_lists.short_description = "Заявки"

    def orders_add(self, obj):
        argss=obj.pk
        link_buttom = reverse ("admin:catalog_order_add") + "?" + "order_customer=" + str(argss)
        return mark_safe(f'<a class="button" label="Заявки" href="{link_buttom}">Створити</a>')
    orders_add.short_description = "Додати заявку"



@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['order_customer', 'order_date', 'order_number', 'order_adress', 'oder_brand', 'butt_ord']

    def butt_ord(self, obj):
        link_buttom = reverse('downloadWordorder', args=[obj.pk])
        return mark_safe(f'<a class="button" label="Заявка" href="{link_buttom}">Заявку</a>')
    butt_ord.short_description = "Сформувати"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmjZO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDgGR.png)

Comment: can you explain more precisely what is the issue here?

Comment: I edited the question. I want a dynamic Add button of the Order model. If the view is filtered by Customer.id, the Add button accepts this value, and when clicked, the Order form opens with the Customer.id already filled in. Otherwise, the Add button accepted the default value and opened the Order record creation form without the Customer.id value filled in